# Thymeleaf: Error parsing a Javascript expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf template with this piece of code

```
<a href="#" th:onclick="'performAjaxCall('@{/mymenupricesummary/pricealarm/1/{id}(id=${menuPriceSummary.menu.id})}');'">
```

But when I start the app I got this error:

```
Could not parse as expression: "javascript: ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript function call with Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526037/javascript-function-call-with-thymeleaf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to format this correctly.  This works for me:

```
<a href="#" th:onclick="'performAjaxCall(\'' + @{/mymenupricesummary/pricealarm/1/{id}(id=${menuPriceSummary.menu.id})} + '\');'">
```